# How to properly filter data using checkboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core project and I got a problem.

In the view, I have a code like this

```
<div class="check-box-inner mt-10">
 <h4 class="title">Power (W) </h4>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
     <input name="power_cold" value="1000" type="checkbox" id="power_cold1">
     <label for="power_cold1">Less 2000 </label>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
     <input name="power_cold" value="3000" type="checkbox" id="power_cold2">
     <label for="power_cold2">2000-3000</label>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
     <input name="power_cold" value="4000" type="checkbox" id="power_cold3">
     <label for="power_cold3">3000-4000</label>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
      <input name="power_cold" value="5000" type="checkbox" id="power_cold4">
      <label for="power_cold4">4000-5000</label>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
      <input name="power_cold" value="30000" type="checkbox" id="power_cold5">
      <label for="power_cold5">Больше 5000</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

In the controller, I get it this way. And I am trying to filter the data using Linq.
But I don't know how I can apply a less or more condition to a list of values.How can this problem be solved? Maybe I should return data in a different format from the view?

```
 public ActionResult Summary(List<int> power_cold)
{
   ProductLis products = new ProductLis()
   {
      Products = repository.Products.Where(f=>f.Power<=(something)&&f.Power>=(something))
   }
}
```

Comment: Try || instead of &&. Your predicate is true only when `Power` equals `something`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using complex ViewModel for Controller Action to rich your goal:

```
<div class="check-box-inner mt-10">
 <h4 class="title">Power (W) </h4>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
     <input name="LessThen2000" value="true" type="checkbox" id="power_cold1">
     <label for="power_cold1">Less 2000 </label>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
     <input name="Between2000And3000" value="true" type="checkbox" id="power_cold2">
     <label for="power_cold2">2000-3000</label>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
     <input name="Between3000And4000" value="true" type="checkbox" id="power_cold3">
     <label for="power_cold3">3000-4000</label>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
      <input name="Between4000And5000" value="true" type="checkbox" id="power_cold4">
      <label for="power_cold4">4000-5000</label>
 </div>
 <div class="filter-check-box">
      <input name="MoreThen5000" value="true" type="checkbox" id="power_cold5">
      <label for="power_cold5">Больше 5000</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

And ViewModel which represents this structure:

```
public class GetSummaryInput{

   public bool LessThen2000 {get;set;}

   public bool Between2000And3000 {get;set;}

   public bool Between3000And4000{get;set;}

   public bool Between4000And5000 {get;set;}

   public bool MoreThen5000 {get;set;}

}
```

Then inside action use it like this:

```
public ActionResult Summary(GetSummaryInput input)
{
   IQueriable<Products> query = repository.Products;

   if(input.LessThen2000){
      query = query.Where(pr=> pr.Power <= 2000);
   }
   
   if(input.Between2000And3000){
      query = query.Where(pr=> pr.Power >= 2000 && pr.Power <= 3000);
   }

   //other properties in the same way 

}
```